# Two Sons, One Father

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

You are an inmate in a concentration camp/prison. A sadistic guard is about to hang your son who tried to escape and wants you to pull the chair from underneath him. He says that if you don’t he will not only kill your son but some other innocent inmate as well. You don’t have any doubt that he means what he says. What will you do?

Comment: I did not downvote, but I do suggest you edit the question to be more specific.  With the origin post you could have hundred of answers on how the father can just kill the guard / save the son / etc etc

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is

> you will pull the chair out from underneath him, because it's under the guard, not the son.

Comment: Can you give evidence?

Comment: It says in the puzzle that the guard "wants you to pull the chair from underneath him."  It never specifics who "him" is.  It's at least a theory, although I hope it's right.

Comment: @bleh It's a lateral-thinking question. Here the pronoun in "underneath him" is being interpreted as referring to the guard instead of the son.

Comment: or the guard is his son. what a TWIST

Comment: @Slepz Ha, that's what I was just thinking about, based on the title...